# IIS some application cannot be access and keep loading

Tags: c#, iis

I have some application hosted in iis. For some application, it can be loaded. But for some application, it cannot be loaded. I try to copy the web folder to the application that cannot be loaded, but the application still cannot be loaded. I check the IIS log, for the application that can be accessed, it will write log to iis log. However, for application that cannot be loaded, no record is written to the iis log. I have serveral application that have the same problem. And other serveral application that can be loaded. What is the problem of iis?

Comment: Please define what is "cannot be loaded". If it is too difficult to describe, at least show some screen shots.

Comment: @LexLi When I open the home page of the application, in browser, it just keep loading, and no any content is displayed

Comment: Use the browser developer tools or Fiddler to analyze deeper please. What packets are sent behind the scene might indicate what exactly happens. Without such analysis, you are far away from knowing the cause. If you find it too difficult to work on, open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com